# A map-like class that has a function that fills a range of keys with specified value

Tags: c++

Assume I am implementing a map-like class that has a function that fills a range of keys with specified value:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>>
>
class strange_map
{
public:

    // Assigns entire [a, b] range to the value.
    template <class KeyA, class KeyB, class U>
    void fill_range(KeyA&& a, KeyB&& b, U&& value)
    {
        // ...
        auto i = some_internal_map.find(a);
        // ...
        some_internal_map.emplace(std::forward<KeyA>(a), 
            SomeInternalRange{ std::forward<KeyB>(b), std::forward<U>(value)) };
        // ...
    }

private:

    struct SomeInternalRange { Key b, T value };
    std::map<Key, SomeInternalRange> some_internal_map;
};
```

How do I pass keys and value parameters? By value or by reference?

Should I use forwarding references as I did above?

Usage:

```
using StrangeMap = strange_map<int, std::string>;
StrangeMap map;
map.fill_range(1, 3, "a");

std::string b = "b";
map.fill_range(5, 7, b);
```

Is it a good idea to pass value parameter by value, but keys by reference (because value is always moved or copied, but keys can be used only with `some_internal_map.find` and are not inserted if a range already exists)?

```
    template <class KeyA, class KeyB>
    void fill_range(KeyA&& a, KeyB&& b, T value);
```

Comment: What is your assignment? Why do you need to create a new class, instead of a function? Why can't you use inheritance from `std::map` and just add the needed functionality?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude internally it contains a map of ranges of a different type and I am interested not in how to implement it, but how to use forwarding references in a right way in this particular case.

Comment: This seems very underspecified.  How is a "range" defined?  Merely providing a start and end value does not specify a range.  What if `int` as the key is replaced by `float`?  Or `std::complex`?  How are overlapping ranges and their values to be stored?

Comment: @AndrewHenle there is no `Compre` template parameter that works with `std::complex`. The implementation simply compares `a` and `b` with `key_comp(a, b)`. `Key` can be any type we can define a `Compare` to work with.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Any type can have a suitable compare defined, including `std::complex`. Mathematically such an operation isn't defined, but there's nothing stopping one from deciding to use a lexicographical comparison there.

Comment: @Kyle ok, then `std::complex` is allowed.